# How to change the text on a button every time the button is clicked?

Tags: c#, button, text

I want my button to be a Start/Stop button at the same time. It starts with the Start as Text property, but when it's clicked I want the Text on the button to be "Stop". And then go on in infinity...

I have tried this, but unfortunately the button doesn't change text when I click it:

My button is declared as a member variable in this class. In the first method I've used the `EventHandler start.Click += StartButton;`
The second method is the `StartButton` method. I want that this method changes the Text property of the Button. Then I did this:

```
public void StartButton(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    if (start.Text == "Start")
    {

        start.Text = "Stop";
        
    }

    else
        start.Text = "Start";

}
```

Comment: Please specify the UI framework you use (WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, Unity, ...)

Comment: "My button is declared as a member variable in this class."  And is that class the same class as the Form?  Or did you declare a new class and add a declaration for a button there.  If so, the button you are working with is not the same as the one you see on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

try to use else if

should be working

```
if (start.Text == "Start") 
{ start.Text = "Stop"; }  
else if (start.Text == "Stop")
 {start.Text = "Start"; }
```

else if is used when the first condition is false

if will always check both.. so there will be no change / one change only if used correctly

Hope I could help you :)

Comment: Please explain how this code would work better than the code the OP already has. See [answer] for more tips on what makes a good answer.